# Output with the same number of digits of pi as the length of the code

Tags: code-golf, pi, floating-point, self-referential

Your challenge is to print `x` digits of pi where `x` is your code length.

Examples:

```
Source code (length) -> output
foo!        (4)         3.141
foobar      (6)         3.14159
kinda long  (10)        3.141592653
+++++       (5)         3.1415
123456789   (9)         3.14159265
```

You can use `floor(π/10 * 10code_length) / 10code_length - 1` to determine the number of digits you need to print. Note that the decimal point does not count as a digit of pi - so code of length 3 should have output `3.14`, of length 4.

Rules:

- Your code length must be larger than three characters.
- You may not use any standard loopholes.
- You may use any standard allowed output methods.
- You may not read your source to determine code length.
- **You may not use a builtin pi constant.**
- Pi must be *completely accurate* and not approximated.
- The decimal point in the output is necessary. If you choose to output via return value, you must return a floating point integer.
- The goal of this challenge is to find the shortest solution in each language, not the shortest language for the solution. Don't be afraid to post a solution in a language when a shorter solution is posted in the same language as long as your solution uses a different method.

Comment: ...so would [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzO3IL@oRKG4MregkqugKDOvREEDzNFLLEnM0zDU1DLR1MvTMDHS/P8fAA) be valid or not?

Comment: (edit ^ [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzO3IL@oRKG4MregkqugKDOvREEDzNFLLEnM0zDU1DLR1MvTMDHWtP7/HwA) even (rounding))

Comment: “Code length” ← in bytes or in characters?

Comment: @Lynn Bytes, as usual.

Comment: Is just `3` allowed?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere *Your code length must be larger than three characters.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>9</s> 4 bytes

As short as it can allowably get :)

Includes an unprintable (reverse line feed, charcode 141) after the `#`.

```
3.#
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=My4jjQ==&input=)

In Japt, any character following `#` is converted to its character code and appended to any digits or decimal points which may precede it, in this case the `3.`

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, 18 bytes

using zeta function

[image]

```
Sqrt[6Zeta@2]~N~18
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvs/uLCoJNosKrUk0cEots6vztDif0BRZl6JgkPafwA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
“Œı⁸Ç’÷ȷ8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9qZWxsef//4oCcxZLEseKBuMOH4oCZw7fItzj//w)

Outputs `3.14159265`

**How it Works**

```
“Œı⁸Ç’     - The integer 314159265
      ÷    - divide
       ȷ8  - The integer 100000000
```

Comment: Pi is not being calculated!

Comment: yes it is, dividing 314159265 by 100000000 :-)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
3;⁽4ƒṾ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Y@lHjXpNjkx7u3Pf/PwA)**

Prints `3,14159` with the allowed "European" decimal separator, `,`.

#### How?

```
3;⁽4ƒṾ - Main link: no arguments
3      - literal 3                3
  ⁽4ƒ  - base 250 literal 14159   14159
 ;     - concatenate              [3,14159]
     Ṿ - unevaluate               ['3', ',', '1', '4', '1', '5', '9']
       - implicit print           3,14159
```

Comment: That digit list looks odd. I think there is an extra `,'` in there.

Comment: You can do `-ÆAær5` and use `.` instead of `,`, but then it would be the same as my Jelly solution.

Answer (score 6):

## VBA (Excel), 15 bytes

```
MsgBox 4*Atn(1)
```

Output:
3.14159265358979

I think this is not acceptable as I golfed it just to fit the length of the PI. The un-golfed length of it is 17 bytes. D:

Comment: Looks as though you have not yet been welcomed, so, welcome to the site!

Comment: Oh, Thank you, Sir! :D

Comment: Isn't `Atn` arctangent? I'm not sure if this is allowed... asking OP

Comment: I thought OP is referring for built-in PI only. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 64 bytes

```python
print("3.%d"%int("SIXW57LUPVBUA10HBQJOL57QLF54UT0U00KIN32O",36))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8lYTzVFSRXMDPaMCDc19wkNCHMKdTQ08HAK9PL3MTUP9HEzNQkNMQg1MPD29DM28lfSMTbT1Pz/HwA)

Comment: The Python 2 equivalent is 60 bytes `print'3.%d'%int('3p3aqd50r7654t9ywkfkgsm0yx0bikcluxlhsm',36)`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan python 2 in 59: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8K2wFbXxMCcqzwjMye1rsAKKKBvpFWhX6BtpGVooKVlamFdoG1rxFVQlJlXom6sp66dUJEQbWhVEPv/PwA

Comment: @primo looks like one to post if&when...

Comment: @JonathanAllan if you mean when it's reopened, it is now.

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), 130 bytes

```
f\left(\right)=\frac{\operatorname{floor}\left(10^{128}\cdot 4\sum_{k=1}^{9^9}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+1}}{2k-1}\right)}{10^{128}}
```

[image]

The source code for this (Which can be accessed by copy and pasting inside and outside of Desmos) isn't optimal when generated using the Desmos editor, so a few bytes of whitespace were golfed down where possible.

This defines a function `f` which takes no arguments returns pi, calculated using the [Gregory Sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GregorySeries.html) to `k=9^9` *(I can't confirm this is accurate enough, however I am of the believe that it is, it can be made more accurate with a greater value of k)* it then floors the result to `128` decimal places, which, alongside the `3.`, is the length of the source code.

[Try it online!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sj7sokmfrx)

Comment: How does one actually see the result - I only see `3.14159265617`, am I looking in the wrong place; do I need to hit a button?

Comment: Desmos doesn't defaultly print to as many decimal places as provided, but the value should still be accurate.

Comment: That is disappointing since the challenge is "to print..."

Comment: "The decimal point in the output is necessary. If you choose to output via return value, you must return a floating point integer." which makes this valid.

Comment: I feel the intent of that statement was not to allow for less precision but to ensure a decimal separator. Mind you I don't think your answer is bad.

Comment: The precision is there, it's just that Desmos can't print it all in a single output, but it can return from a function fine.

Answer (score 4):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
4ΘΞ“6⌡υ
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=NCV1MDM5OCV1MDM5RSV1MjAxQzYldTIzMjEldTAzQzU_)

Explanation:

```
4ΘΞ“     push 31415
    6⌡   6 times do
      υ    divide by 10
```

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 5 bytes

```
3.14F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/31jP0MTt/38A)

#### How it works

```
3.14   e# Push 3.14.
    F  e# Push 15.
```

Comment: If only you could've done `3.E`. :P, either way, amazing abuse of IO.

Comment: Was going to post `3'.EF`, but then I saw this answer...

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
”i‴Ａχ:&”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/7@gKDOvREHJWM/QxNDU0shM6f///7pl/3WLcwA)

Just a compressed string.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, 16 bytes

```js
_=>Math.acos(-1)
```

```js
f=
_=>Math.acos(-1)
console.log(f())
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 5 bytes

```
3FBρσ
```

Explanation:

```
3      Push 3
 FB    F pushes 45, B converts it into a character code, '.'
   ρ   Push 14
    σ  Push 15
Implicitly concatenate and print stack
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3/39jN6Xzj@eb//wE)

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 6 bytes

```
10○⍟-1
```

Takes the imaginary part of ln(-1).

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=10%u25CB%u235F-1&run)

Comment: Hey, welcome back @Uriel! Nice one, I wasn't thinking of anything like that (with logs of negative numbers), nice job!

Comment: @Zacharý thanks, just dropped a visit and couldn't help answering this :P

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 16 bytes

```
17j15":4*_3 o.1:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuY6BgpWCgq@cc5OP239A8y9BUycpEK95YIV/P0Oq/Jldqcka@Qpq6@n8A)

Similar to the VBA answer. Outputs: `3.141592653589793`.

Comment: "You may not use a builtin macro or constant to determine pi." Funny, it's your comment

Comment: Your output is 17 bytes, not 16.

Comment: @ATaco exactly, it's 16 digits

Comment: @LeakyNun it doesn't. `_3 o.1` calculates atan(1). As you may have known, I'm well aware of the rules.

Answer (score 2):

## [Math.JS](http://mathjs.org), 17 bytes.

```
     log(-1,e).im
```

*That's 5 leading spaces*

This calculates [image] to 15 decimal places, and implicitly prints it.

[Try It Online!](https://a-ta.co/math/&ICAgICBsb2coLTEsZSkuaW0=)

Comment: Well, technically this calculates the imaginary portion of `ln(-1)`, but since it's a purely imaginary number, it's equivalent to dividing by `i`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
3•∊&SK•)'.ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f@FHDokcdXWrB3kCGprre4b3//wMA)

```
COMMAND     # CURRENT STACK         | EXPLANATION
------------#-----------------------+-----------------------------------
3           # [3]                   | Push 3.
 •∊&SK•     # [3, 1415926535]       | Push compressed base-255 number 1415926535.
       )    # [[3,1415926535]]      | Wrap the 2 to an array.
        '.  # [[3,1415926535],'.']  | Push a decimal point.
          ý # ['3.1415926535']      | Join 3 and 1415926535 with a decimal point.
```

---

***USING BUILT-INS:***

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
žq5£
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6L5C00OL//8HAA)

---

`3žs` doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: @Zacharý did I miss something? Why is that special xD?

Comment: It's in my username, and also, can you add an explanation?

Comment: @Zacharý HA! My brain was going through all the possible funny PPCG-related jokes it could be, coming up blank. I overthink crap.

Comment: @Zacharý also, added.

Comment: If MY had implicit IO, there would be no way to beat `E3.`, I'm mad at **my**self now :p.

Comment: @Zacharý can I get a link to "MY"? If you want a comment link use: "[MY](<link to my github>)".

Comment: Here: https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src. MY does have a TIO (it's not synced due to me being suspended from chat for just pushing it way too far, (if anyone wants to ask Dennis to pull MY for me, that would be nice)).

Comment: @Zacharý I have requested a pull but [apparently it doesn't work](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40074989#40074989).

Comment: There, I fixed that >_<. It can hopefully be pulled successfully.

Comment: `2žs` does work now and for the non-built-in version you could have `•Iò₅U•8°/`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
-ÆAær5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/3cJvj4WVFpv//AwA)

Uses a different approach than the other Jelly answers.

### How?

`-ÆA` is inverse cosine of `-1` (which is pi), `ær5` retrieves the needed section. It worked out so rounding is equivalent to truncation in this case

Answer (score 2):

## [ForceLang](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/ForceLang), 269 bytes

```
set S 0x5F258E476FC1B3B5571012206C637089460E41E814CB071E61431B5F0671F551D18D2C5D2D3A2565E408C6DE8D753F595B6E9979C3866D1C9965008DCFB02E3BD11D21DFFAF17978F05C8BBACF55A5ED5E90B1D8CAD8736AA4B728EB342B453F86353DB371D322B6A98613BC5CCB00AC2.mult 1e-270
io.write S.toString 268
```

Comment: Link to the [language on github](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/ForceLang) at least.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
-1X;V9:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X9cwwjrM0krz/38A)

Explanation:

```
-1      % number literal
X;      % inverse cosine (radians), giving pi
V       % convert to string
9       % specify precision
:)      % keep first 9 characters - 8 digits of precision
```

Saved one byte thanks to Luis Mendo!

Answer (score 2):

## RPL (HP48), 86.5 bytes, 87 digits [Does this count?]

```
« GROB 8 43
14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803
→STR 9 OVER SIZE SUB 2 "." REPL »
```

GROB is an image keyword. The 2 numbers that follow are width and height. The hexadecimal digits that follow are bitmap. That's 1 byte of storage for every 2 digits plus the image metadata.

Empty program `« »` takes 10 bytes. A command takes 2.5 bytes. A float takes 10.5 bytes, but if it's equal to a single digit integer, it can take 2.5 bytes.

HP48 stores 4 rather than 8 bits at each memory location, so a byte occupies 2 consecutive locations (low endian). Often 20-bit chunks are used, and they do take 2.5 bytes (not 3).

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 7 bytes

```
round(4tan⁻¹(1),6

round(2sin⁻¹(1),6

round(cos⁻¹(-1),6
```

These three statements will print `3.141593`.

---

**Note:**  TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does ***not*** equal byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 16 bytes

```julia
show(acos(-1))##
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vzgjv1wjMTm/WEPXUFNTWfl/cn5KanxOal56SYaCrYKhGVdBUWZeSU6ehiaclZaTn1@kkZSZrnG@QVPf0EBBS8HQIA5Jo6aCPkhEA9ksXQWg@f8B)

This is the default precision printed, I sadly have to add 2 dummy characters but I don't think it's possible to make it shorter

Comment: No bytes improvement, but there is no unused characters in [`print(4*atan(1))`](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69Ew0QrsSQxT8NQU/N/cn5KanxOal56SYaCrYKhGRdYRU6ehiaclZaTn1@kkZSZrnG@QVPf0EBBS8HQIA5Jo6aCPkhEA9ksXQWQ6QA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src), 7 bytes

```
’2ō"8↑↵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//9Rw0yjo71KFo/aJj5q2/r////oaAsdBXMdBcNYHYVoEyCto2AMYprqKIBQbCwA)

### How?

- `’`, decrement the top of the stack (`0` is popped if empty, making the stack `[-1]`). (Same symbol as Jelly)
- `2`, push `2`.
- `ō`, since the top of the stack is two, discard the `2`, pop `n`, then push `acos(n)` (in radians, this gives pi, this symbol is `o` with a negative sign on top of it. `o` (for normal trig) comes from APL).
- `"`, pop the top element of the stack and push it as a string.
- `8`, push `8`.
- `↑`, pop `a` then `b`, push `b[:a]` (This is another symbol taken from APL).
- `↵`, output with a new line (OUTPUT <- STACK).

Comment: Then add implicit output :P

Comment: I'm keeping true to the nature of MY, I might make an improved version with actual syntax, and *definitely* with implicit output

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 15 bytes

```hs
 acos(-1)-3e-15
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfZvtfITE5v1hD11BT1zhV19D0f25iZp6CrUJKvgIXZ0FpSXBJkU@egopCcUZ@uUKZtraSgoaStjaIp5GTmpdekqEBkdEEmqCtraCkkJKZnllSrKn0HwA)

Using @JungHwanMin formula.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 40 bytes

```perl
}{$\=$\/~(2*$_)*~$_+2for-130..-2
```

Requires the command line option `-pMbignum`, counted as 8.

**Sample Useage:**

```perl
$ perl -pMbignum test.pl < /dev/null
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197
```

I apologize for no TIO link, it doesn't seem to support `bignum` (or an unmatched opening brace...).

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 16 bytes

```
"]a:5;."3no>n<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/Xyk20cpUyvpQr56ScV6@XZ7N//8A)

There's a couple of unprintables in there, with the first having value 26 and the second 141.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 99 bytes

```c
i;main(){for(;i<46;)printf(i++?"%02d":"3.",i[L"0;5:a]î.+& O2TÅ©']KiR J^-\N¤>cV0ý*uO"]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09Dszotv0jDOtPGxMxas6AoM68kTSNTW9teSdXAKEXJSslYT0knM9pHyeBQr7WUqVVi7OF1elLaagr@RjIhh1sPrVSP9c4MUvCK042R8zu0hE3GjiM5TIbZ4PBerVI2f6VYTeva//8B)

Hardcode 99 bottle of digits

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3C%60.ttZ4+T&debug=0), 9 bytes

```
<`.ttZ4 T
```

**[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3C%60.ttZ4+T&debug=0)**

Works with the fact that [image].

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```ruby
->{Math.acos -1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf167aN7EkQy8xOb9YQdew9n9BaUmxQlp07H8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 16 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window functions that takes no input and output to any of Excel VBA's STDOUTs

<sub>*Each line represents a separate function that returns Pi of length 16*</sub>

```vba
?Mid(4*Atn(1),1)
```

```vba
?Str([Acos(-1)])
```

```vba
Debug.?4*Atn(1);
```

```vba
MsgBox[Acos(-1)]
```

```vba
[A1]="=ACOS(-1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 16 bytes

```matlab
vpa(acos(-1),16)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/rCBRIzE5v1hD11BTx9BM8/9/AA)

I'm having a hard time imagining how this could be shorter...

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 14 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42MTm/WEPXwMBQ0/r/fwA)

```
<?=acos(-001);
```

A bit tricky, but the precition of `M_PI` is `3.1415926535898`

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck (32 bit), <s>672</s> 660 bytes

```
++++++[->++++++++++<]>[->+++++++++++<]>[<+>>>>>>>>++++++++++<<<<<<<-]>+++++[<+++++++++>-]+>>>>>>+[<<+++[>>[-<]<[>]<-]>>[>+>]<[<]>]>[[->>>>+<<<<]>>>+++>-]<[<<<<]<<<<<<<<+[->>>>>>>>>>>>[<+[->>>>+<<<<]>>>>>]<<<<[>>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<<<<<-[<<++++++++++>>-]>>>[<<[<+<<+>>>-]<[>+<-]<++<<+>>>>>>-]<<[-]<<-<[->>+<-[>>>]>[[<+>-]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>+<<<-[>>+<<-]<]<<<<+>>>>>>>>[-]>[<<<+>>>-]<<++++++++++<[->>+<-[>>>]>[[<+>-]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>+>[<<+<+>>>-]<<<<+<+>>[-[-[-[-[-[-[-[-[-<->[-<+<->>]]]]]]]]]]<[+++++[<<<++++++++<++++++++>>>>-]<<<<+<->>>>[>+<<<+++++++++<->>>-]<<<<<[>>+<<-]+<[->-<]>[>>.<<<<[+.[-]]>>-]>[>>.<<-]>[-]>[-]>>>[>>[<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>-]<<-]]>>[-]<<<[-]<<<<<<<<]
```

All credit should go to Felix Nawothnig's [yapi.b](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?file=https://copy.sh/brainfuck/prog/yapi.b).

Should you decide to downvote, please leave a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 16 bytes

```perl6
{4*atan       1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2kQrsSQxTwECDGv/W3MVJ1YqpFn/BwA)

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Ojkjv0DhfIu@kY5x7X9rruLESoU06/8A) using tau

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
»Øȯ\œ»k6/
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCQiVDMyU5OCVDOCVBRiU1QyVDNSU5MyVDMiVCQms2JTJGJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JmZsYWdzPQ==)

Compressed integer 314159265 divided by 100000000.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kP5ɱ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWtQNSVDOSVCMSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSZmbGFncz0=)

Using built-in Pi constant.